# What are the required data for pyplot trisurf?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot make it clear for me, how pyplot trisurf works. All the examples I have seen on the Internet use numpy, pandas and other stuff impeding understanding this tool

Pyplot docs say it requires `X`, `Y` and `Z` as 1D arrays. But if I try to provide them, it issues a `RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.` I tried using python `list` and numpy `arange`

What are exactly those 1D arrays the tool wants me to provide?

Comment: "All the examples I have seen on the Internet use numpy, pandas and other stuff impeding understanding this tool"
All matplotlib takes is numpy arrays, so I don't understand how numpy arrays can impeded your understanding of the tool.

Comment: @JodyKlymak regular 2d plots work with lists with no problem

Comment: @JohanC let this even be [1, 2, 3] for each dimension. I only want to get the point how I should provide the dimensions

Comment: My point is that you aren't going to get far using matplotlib if you consider numpy arrays exotic.

Comment: @JodyKlymak this is not about whether numpy is exotic or not. This is about why I cannot build a trisurf using python built-in types

Comment: @JohanC you made it! Seems like I got the point. You may put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

`plot_trisurf`, when no explicit triangles are given, connects nearby 3D points with triangles to form some kind of surface. X is a 1D array (or a list) of the x-coordinates of these points (similar for Y and Z).

It doesn't work too well when all points lie on the same 3D line. For example, setting all X, Y and Z to `[1, 2, 3]` will result in a line, not a triangle. P1=(1,1,1), P2=(2,2,2), P3=(3,3,3). The n'th point will use the n'th x, the n'th y and the n'th z. A simple example would be ´ax.plot_trisurf([0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3])`.

Here is an example:

```py
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 9))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_trisurf([0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3],
                 facecolor='cornflowerblue', edgecolor='crimson', alpha=0.4, linewidth=4, antialiased=True)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
N = 12
X = [0] + [sin(a * 2 * pi / N) for a in range(N)]
Y = [0] + [cos(a * 2 * pi / N) for a in range(N)]
Z = [1] + [0 for a in range(N)]
ax2.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z,
                 facecolor='cornflowerblue', edgecolor='crimson', alpha=0.4, linewidth=4, antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot_trisurf]